# log ssl key for pcap from the server

Tags: linux, https, pcap

I'm trying to troubleshoot a system that was recently switched from an HTTP API to HTTPS.
When it was HTTP, I was able to take pcap traces using tcpdump/tethereal/tshark in the linux command line and see the API requests and responses. Now that it's encrypted, I can of course only see details (size, timestamp, etc) of the packets but not the requests/responses themselves.
I know that from the server making the request, I could get the ssl key using the SSLKEYLOGFILE, but I'm not sure how to do that from the responding server or even if there is any way to do that on the fly. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what server you use or in what language the server is implemented in if it is a custom one?

Comment: CentOS release 6.10

Comment: That is an OS, not a server! For generating the SSLKEYLOGFILE you have to reconfigure (or modify) the used server.

Comment: apologies, i misunderstood your question. I am not privy to the inner workings of the API, which is a custom script. i was hoping there was some way of capturing the key exchange from the physical linux box itself

Comment: No, the server does not know what SSL/TLS keys are used, only the server process does know this, therefore you have make the server write the keys log file. Depending on the used server this is easy or very complicated.

Comment: okay. thank you.